# Sorting Javascript array of objects by one value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, react-native

### **Problem**

I am creating a social media app with react native. I am trying to render all of the posts on that app off of a server. I get posts from my server, and they are out of chronological order. I have a timestamp element in each post. How can I sort the posts by this timestamp?

I only included what I thought was the essential information for this question, so please ask if you need more clarification on something.

### **The post objects**

My objects look like this:

```
    Array[
      Object {
         //...
         "time": 1515892254405,
       },
       Object {
         //...
         "time": 1515882632486,
      },
    ]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can't really help you unless you attempted it yourself and came across problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use standard Array.sort() with compare function comparing the time property of each object.

```js
let arr = [{"time": 1515892254405},{"time": 1515882632486}];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a.time - b.time}); // sorts in ascending order
console.log(arr);
arr.sort(function(a, b) {return b.time - a.time}); // sorts in descending order
console.log(arr);
```

More information here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, first, since `objects` is an array, you can simply do this:

```
items.sort(function (item_1, item_2) {
    const { time: t1 } = item_1;
    const { time: t2 } = item_2;

    // This will sort your objects from latest to oldest
    if (t1 > t2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (t1 < t2) {
        return 1;
    } return 0;

    // This will sort your objects from oldest to latest
    // if (t1 > t2) {
    //     return 1;
    // } else if (t1 < t2) {
    //     return -1;
    // } return 0;
});
```

Or, you can install `lodash` module, which is very helpful:

```
npm install --save lodash
```

Then in your app,

```
import _ from 'lodash';
_.sortBy(items, 'time');    // oldest to latest
// _.sortBy(items, 'time').reverse(); // latest to oldest
```

Comment: Yes, it uses native capabilities, meaning that it does not require any linking, therefore, it works with expo/CRNA app. Try it out, I find `lodash` one of the must-use modules when developing RN apps

Comment: thanks! I already accepted the other answer, but I'll try this one out too if I ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

For Sorting String values

```
const sortedData = contacts.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```